# Get Max time according to value in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a question in Sql.

I have a table which I am recording running status changes. This is like in belows.

| Equip | TS | Stat |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 12/31/2020 19:55:10 | 0 |
| A | 01/06/2020 16:47:59 | 1 |
| B | 12/27/2020 21:39:20 | 1 |
| B | 12/29/2020 01:01:32 | 0 |
| C | 12/29/2020 01:00:54 | 1 |
| C | 12/29/2020 01:01:32 | 0 |

On the table there is one currently running equipment.I want to get number of currently running equipments. How can I make this on query? Could you help me about this?

Comment: Running equipment? What tells us it is running

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER` analytical function as follows:

```
select count(*) from
(select t.*,
       row_number() over (partition by equip order by ts desc) as rn
  from t) t
where rn = 1 and stat = 1
```

You can also use `NOT EXISTS` as follows:

```
select count(*) from t
 where t.stat = 1
   and not exists 
       (select 1 from t tt
         where tt.equip = t.equip and tt.ts > t.ts)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with two levels of aggregation.  This query gets currently running equipment:

```
select equip
from t
group by equip
having max(ts) = max(case when stat = 1 then ts end);
```

It checks that the maximum `ts` is the same as the maximum with a status value of `1`.

If you want to count the values rather than return them, then you can use a subquery:

```
select count(*)
from (select equip
      from t
      group by equip
      having max(ts) = max(case when stat = 1 then ts end)
     ) e;
```